# Angular 2 - Routing is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, routes

I try to build a menue with 4 links. Each link should lead to one `html`.

```
<p>
  <a routerLink="/function">Business Function</a>
  <a routerLink="/process">Business Process</a>
  <a routerLink="/appsystem">Appsystem</a>
  <a routerLink="/application">Application</a>
</p>
```

I implemented them in my `app.routing.ts` (imports are included too):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path:"function",
        component: BusinessFunctionComponent,
    },
    {
        path:"process",
        component: BusinessProcessComponent,
    },
    {
        path:"appsystem",
        component: AppsystemComponent,
    },
    {
        path:"application",
        component: ApplicationComponent,
    }
```

For example when I try to reach the `html` `BusinessFunctionComponent` it still shows the same site though it shows the correct URL.

**Business-Function.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-business-function',
  templateUrl: './business-function.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./business-function.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class BusinessFunctionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Can someone help me with this problem as I am quite new to Angular?
Thank you so far!!

**EDIT:**

I moved the links to a navigation bar inside the `index.html`.

```
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-color">
          <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-adjustment" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item activ-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/function">Business Funciton</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/process">Business Process</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/appsystem">Appsystem</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/application">Application</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-style my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <app-root></app-root>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: did you registered all routes in `RouterModule`?

Comment: yes see above. I assume you mean this part of `app.routing.ts` I posted in my question, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-color">
          <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-adjustment" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item activ-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/function">Business Funciton</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/process">Business Process</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/appsystem">Appsystem</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/application">Application</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-style my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Move this to your `app.component.html`

Comment: You should use routerLink instead of href on links. With href your page will be reloaded. Here is api https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink and remove all your href from html

Comment: I’m happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code to your main HTML or to app component html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The routed component will be displayed here.

Comment: thank you this is working!! 
I made a simple change in my code. I moved router links above inside a navigation bar which is located in the `index.html`. I added `router-outlet` too and it isn't working again. See my edit above. Do you have an idea?

Comment: index.html is not associated with any component. router-outlet can be used only in components that are defined in app.module.ts
app.component is recommended

Comment: Its better to create header component and copy your code in header.html then in your app.component.html thats app-root add your app-header and router-outlet or add your code directly to app-component.html

Comment: ok thank you. I solved so far that I copied it in my app.component. But i will keep in mind to create an app-header